# SSIS Package Security

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I am writing a Package for one of my client according to his requirements. Package development is totally complete now time is to protect it with some security.
Is this possible I encrypt all the data with password so no one can open package file(.dtsx) ? and when some one want to execute package he require some other password instead of which I used to protect package file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not native functionality. You can encrypt: Nothing, Sensitive items, Everything. There is no capability to assign one key for development and one for execution.

Instead, the way to restrict execution is through proper security, which is never the last item. If the SSIS package is loading a database, you ensure that only the correct user(s) can do connect/write to the database. If you store the packages in the database, deny them the ability to run the packages. If it's on the file system, set the proper ACL so they can not get to them.

Comment: Actually I will only provide the package to client, he will deploy\execute package own his own with document  guidance. But  I am looking if i can secure development part with a separate Key and allow execution with another key.

Comment: Help me understand then, what would secure development look like as opposed to secure execution

Comment: Development part means we don't want him to view\ modify the scripts, tasks and flows added to fulfill requirements. But they can execute package.